# How to enable browser caching of static content(images, css, js) with Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, caching, tomcat, spring-mvc

How to enable browser caching of static content(images, css, js) with Tomcat? 
Preferable solution will be editingspring MVC config files or web.xml

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try (with changing the values)

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/public-resources/" 
       cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

You can also use an interceptor:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
   <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/static/*"/>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="31556926"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

See the [MVC docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: A tiny correction, the correct tag is "mvc:mapping" instead of "mapping, i.e., correct complete tag is : <mvc:mapping path="/static/*"/>

Comment: which should i use? i am currently in a situation where I've got both, and wonder if both are needed. Seems like I should choose one or the other. are there any benefits using mvc:resources element?

Comment: In case of `304` also client send a HTTP request to server then how it  is benefiting

Comment: @Manish The client will still send a HTTP Request to the server, but the server will reply with a tiny 304 Response instead of transferring your potentially large files (e.g. images, css, js...) back with a 200 Response. In other words, number of requests/responses is the same, but the response may be significantly smaller in size.

Answer (score 1):

If Spring 3.0 is being used, `<mvc:resources>` is one way to implement caching of static resources.  [This link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) has some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Java configuration, you can manage caching parameters using `ResourceHandlerRegistry`, there is example how do I set up different caching preferences for different content types:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
// ...
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/WEB-INF/css/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));

        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/WEB-INF/js/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));

        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/WEB-INF/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
    }

    // ...
}
```