# Cache static contents in weblogic server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, weblogic

I am deploying Java application(Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate3) on Weblogic server. To improve the performance trying cache static contents like images, css and js.
But every time static contents are loaded from server instead of cache.

Anyone have any ideas what this is about and how I can enable cache in weblogic.
I will greatly appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: What method did you use for the static content? Something like this? http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/serving-static-content-on-weblogic-and-glassfish/ http://blog.eisele.net/2010/07/static-content-serving-with-weblogic.html

Comment: I am not using any method for static contents. I want to cache static contents like images, js and css. I have descrbe static contents in dishpather-servlet: <mvc:resources cache-period="31556926" location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

Comment: Ah so more like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123324/how-to-enable-browser-caching-of-static-contentimages-css-js-with-tomcat You should probably tag your question with spring and spring-mvc to see if someone more knowledgeable can come help